# Can admin hijack my home pc

Tags: networking, remote-access, remote-desktop, network-security

While I remote to my work computer from home, can the network admin get access to my home computer? Both my home and work computer are running windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation I have some advice.

First, if you turn off firewall and share password remote desktop to your admin. The answer is **Yes**, he can hijack.

Second, if he installs backdoor before on your PC, he can hijack easy.

**Solution:**

1. Change password remote desktop (using virtual keyboard because may be
   he installs Key logger);
2. Enable Firewall;
3. Using Process Explorer, Antivirus copyright..etc to scan malware.
4. Or you can reinstall your Operation system if you scare and worry.

Good luck!

@Jackie

Answer (score 0):

Depends, if on your PC is installed some backdoor/tool/software that allows to do that. Administrator from work should be considered as inside man and therefore trusted, but You never know. 
There are lot holes in any software, even in windows10, but by default w10 with all monthly incoming security patches is considered to be enough safe from attacks. 
Just a side info, there are 0day vulnerabilities of different software and therefore none is safe from attacks as not all are reported. Even when reported not all companies doing some fast actions.